# Remove or change color of frame around UIWebView document display?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I'm using a `UIWebView` to display a variety of file types (so I can't use a specialized PDF viewer) embedded into my main view (so I can't use a modal document interaction controller). My main view has a background design that clashes with the light gray frame that appears around documents in the `UIWebView`. Does anyone know a way to remove that gray frame, make it transparent or change its color?

I'm familiar with and have used the techniques for [changing the background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547102/cant-change-background-for-uiwebview-in-iphone-sdk) of the `UIWebView` to avoid a "color flash" while it loads, and for [removing the top and bottom shadow](http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/03/transparent-uiwebviews/) that appear when "overscrolling" the web view, but I haven't seen anyone address this gray frame. (It only appears when displaying documents like .doc or .pdf, not when displaying HTML content.) I've hidden all the images that are subviews of the `UIWebView's` scroll view, so apparently this is coming from somewhere else.

Comment: I noticed that a bounty has been added to this question, so I went back to see where my own app ended up. Apparently this issue was resolved by iOS 5, released a couple months after I posted the question. On iOS 5 devices, changing the background color of a UIWebView -- or setting it to clearColor -- works as expected, but on iOS 4 devices the gray frame still appears. I didn't even notice that the problem had gone away, or else I would have posted back here at that time. Does that answer your question, vivianaranha? If not, perhaps you're seeing a different problem in the current iOS.

Comment: Please refer [these link][1] hope this may help you for what you want.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646930/how-to-make-a-transparent-uiwebview/7575777#7575777

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question was written while iOS 4 was current, but in iOS 5 and later, simply setting the backgroundColor and opaque properties of the UIWebView will remove that gray frame:

```
myWebView.opaque = NO;
myWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: It has been working for me up through and including the current iOS version 12.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

You can change WebView's background color by assigning its `backgroundColor` property:

```
myWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; // will make red bakground
```

If you want transparency use `[UIColor clearColor]` instead. But remember - by making your views tranparent you can worsen app's performance.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't change the gray frame that appears around a .doc or .pdf file displayed in a web view. It only changes the color that appears behind that gray frame when the document is loading or overscrolled.

Comment: I think this cannot be done in current SDK. It may be possible in future versions of iOS.

Comment: I didn't expect there would be an official method to do this, but I was hoping someone had a clever workaround like the one to hide the shadow images.

Answer (score 0):

Since this has been around for a while I'll just throw some ideas out there.

You may be able to utilize the [`stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString%3a) method of the [`UIWebView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class to manipulate the document object model if the UIWebView treats the loaded document as a page, but this method has some limitations.

Other than that, the only thing you really have left at your disposal is manipulating the view hierarchy to modify any subviews of the `UIWebView`, but there may not be anything for you manipulate if the `UIWebView` class renders the viewer directly rather than creating a hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is not possible to remove the border from a UIWebView but could you not use `CGContextDrawPDFPage()` as Apple show here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score -1):

You need a bunch of CoreAnimation magic:

```
- (void) hideShadowInLayer:(CALayer *) layer
{
    for (CALayer *l in layer.sublayers) {
        l.shadowOpacity = 0;
        [self hideShadowInLayer:l];
    }
}

- (void) hideShadows
{
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setValue:(id) kCFBooleanTrue forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];
    [self hideShadowInLayer:webView.layer];
    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

You need to perform `hideShadows` method somewhere AFTER loading your document and while you are scrolling it (I guess `scrollViewDidScroll` of `webView.scrollView.delegate` is a good place). You also need to include `QuartzCore` framework to your project.

What's going on here:

Any view uses something called `layer` for rendering. Layers can have its own hierarchy and every layer can have its own border and shadow, so the frame that annoying you is the shadow of one of them. Bad thing - UIWebView recreates it while scrolling - so you need to use this method constantly. And I guess `shadowOpacity` has a default animation attached to it, so you need CATransaction to disable it.

Comment: This is pretty cool, and in my testing, the shadows are not recreated during scrolling or zooming. However, the question was how to change the color of the frame, not how to remove the shadows!

Comment: ok, add 
`if (l.shadowOpacity>0) { 
   l.shadowColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
}` 
instead of 
`l.shadowOpacity = 0;`
it will change the color of your frame

Comment: As far as I understand, "light gray frame that appears around documents" is CALayer shadows, as I mentioned in my answer. So, my code - is removing it and make the pdf file float as it is, without border around each page

Comment: Sorry, there's a background color that defaults to light gray, and then the shadows on top of that are separate. I think this is confusing because the question is from iOS 4; all we need now is to change the UIWebView background color to eliminate the frame I was talking about. I just added a comment to my original question above.

Comment: Ooops, you are right, it doesn't solve a problem in iOS4, sorry.

Comment: Doesn't work in iOS12.
Please amend your response as you later replied it didn't solve anything.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
self.webview.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

for (UIView* subView in [self.webview subviews])
{
    if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
        for (UIView* shadowView in [subView subviews])
        {
            if ([shadowView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
                [shadowView setHidden:YES];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This may help you. :-)